# Using pywin32 (XLWINGS) how do you read the text of an existing comment?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, xlwings

I can set and delete comments in an Excel sheet but am unable to get (read)the contents of an existing comment. xlwings doesn't have a method for it so you need to drop down to the com object.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Workbook.active()
xw.Range('A1').api.AddComment('Some Text')
xw.Range('A1').api.DeleteComment()
xw.Range('A1').api.AddComment('More Text')
# Sadness on my best effort so far
comment_text = xw.Range('A1').api.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

Comment: That gets you the value of the cell not the value of the comment.  Thanks anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write excel comments using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729544/how-to-write-excel-comments-using-python)

Comment: My problem is reading the comment not writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the OP nor the suggested answer works for me. Here is how I did it in xlwings version 0.11.5 (on windows if that matters, Excel 2013, 2016, 2019):

Adding comments to a cell (Please note you have to clear the comment if a comment already exists!):

```
import xlwings as xw

path_to_excel_file = r'c:\temp\test.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(path_to_excel_file)
sheet = wb.sheet['Sheet1']
coordinate = (1,1)
comment = "test comment"
sheet.range(coordinate).api.ClearComments()
sheet.range(coordinate).api.AddComment(comment)
```

Reading the value of a comment:

```
import xlwings as xw

path_to_excel_file = r'c:\temp\test.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(path_to_excel_file)
sheet = wb.sheet['Sheet1']
coordinate = (1,1)

xlsx_comment = sheet.range(coordinate).api.comment
if xlsx_comment is not None:
    print(xlsx_comment.text())
else:
    print("No comment in this cell.")
```

I always have to google how to do it and I come across this thread so I figured this should be documented somewhere. Happy hunting!

Answer (score -1):

> **Question**: ... how do you read the text of an existing comment?
>   My problem is reading the comment not writing it

Do not disturb yourself at the linked Title [How to write excel comments using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729544/how-to-write-excel-comments-using-python) , the Answer showing also **reading**. The used Example is confusing as it shows the passed *Comment* as returned String:

```
>>> sheet.Range("A1").Comment.Text("Hello World")
u'Hello World'
```

> [Comment.Text method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.comment.text.aspx)
>
> ```
> returnValue = instance.Text(Text, Start, Overwrite)
> ```
>
> Parameters
>   `Text` Type: System.Object **Optional** Object. The text to be added.
>   `Start` Type: System.Object **Optional** Object. The character number where the added text will be placed. If this argument is omitted, any existing text in the comment is deleted.
>   `Overwrite` Type: System.Object **Optional** Object. True to overwrite the existing text. The default value is False (text is inserted).
>   Return value
>   Type: `System.String`

As **all** Parameter **Optional**, `Text()` return the Comment Text.

```
>>> sheet.Range("A1").Comment.Text()
u'Hello World'
```

Comment: I am still doing something wrong as its not working.  I need to write some test code.